# 'java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Lorg/jacoco/agent/rt/internal_8ff85ea/Offline;' Error on Mixpanel

Tags: flutter, mixpanel

I recently integrated mixpanel on my flutter mobile app. At first there we're no problems. But after a while of using it, I cannot launch the app anymore, and it displays the error below:

```
E/flutter (29702): [ERROR:flutter/shell/platform/android/platform_view_android_jni_impl.cc(43)] java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Lorg/jacoco/agent/rt/internal_8ff85ea/Offline;
E/flutter (29702):  at com.mixpanel.android.mpmetrics.MixpanelAPI.$jacocoInit(Unknown Source:13)
E/flutter (29702):  at com.mixpanel.android.mpmetrics.MixpanelAPI.<clinit>(Unknown Source:0)
E/flutter (29702):  at com.mixpanel.android.mpmetrics.MixpanelAPI.getInstance(Unknown Source:0)
E/flutter (29702):  at com.mixpanel.mixpanel_flutter.MixpanelFlutterPlugin.handleInitialize(MixpanelFlutterPlugin.java:182)
E/flutter (29702):  at com.mixpanel.mixpanel_flutter.MixpanelFlutterPlugin.onMethodCall(MixpanelFlutterPlugin.java:57)
E/flutter (29702):  at io.flutter.plugin.common.MethodChannel$IncomingMethodCallHandler.onMessage(MethodChannel.java:233)
E/flutter (29702):  at io.flutter.embedding.engine.dart.DartMessenger.handleMessageFromDart(DartMessenger.java:85)
E/flutter (29702):  at io.flutter.embedding.engine.FlutterJNI.handlePlatformMessage(FlutterJNI.java:692)
E/flutter (29702):  at android.os.MessageQueue.nativePollOnce(Native Method)
E/flutter (29702):  at android.os.MessageQueue.next(MessageQueue.java:386)
E/flutter (29702):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:175)
E/flutter (29702):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7625)
E/flutter (29702):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
E/flutter (29702):  at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:524)
E/flutter (29702):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:987)
E/flutter (29702): Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "org.jacoco.agent.rt.internal_8ff85ea.Offline" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/system/framework/android.test.mock.jar", zip file "/system/framework/org.apache.http.legacy.boot.jar", zip file "/system/framework/android.test.runner.jar", zip file "/data/app/ph.dudu.duduph-xxdPe23WLh6USaFzF3Frsw==/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/ph.dudu.duduph-xxdPe23WLh6USaFzF3Frsw==/lib/arm64, /data/app/ph.dudu.duduph-xxdPe23WLh6USaFzF3Frsw==/base.apk!/lib/arm64-v8a, /system/lib64, /product/lib64]]
E/flutter (29702):  at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:134)
E/flutter (29702):  at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:379)
E/flutter (29702):  at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:312)
E/flutter (29702):  ... 15 more
E/flutter (29702): 
F/flutter (29702): [FATAL:flutter/shell/platform/android/platform_view_android_jni_impl.cc(942)] Check failed: CheckException(env). 
F/libc    (29702): Fatal signal 6 (SIGABRT), code -6 (SI_TKILL) in tid 29702 (ph.dudu.duduph), pid 29702 (ph.dudu.duduph)
*** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** ***
Build fingerprint: 'HUAWEI/INE-LX2/HWINE:9/HUAWEIINE-LX2/9.1.0.318C636:user/release-keys'
Revision: '0'
ABI: 'arm64'
Happend: 'Fri Oct  8 19:44:13 2021
'
SYSVMTYPE: Art
APPVMTYPE: Art
pid: 29702, tid: 29702, name: ph.dudu.duduph  >>> ph.dudu.duduph <<<
signal 6 (SIGABRT), code -6 (SI_TKILL), fault addr --------
Abort message: '[FATAL:flutter/shell/platform/android/platform_view_android_jni_impl.cc(942)] Check failed: CheckException(env). 
'
    x0  0000000000000000  x1  0000000000007406  x2  0000000000000006  x3  0000000000000008
    x4  0000000000000000  x5  0000000000000000  x6  0000000000000000  x7  7f7f7f7f7f7f7f7f
    x8  0000000000000083  x9  d8cb342cbbd165b9  x10 0000000000000000  x11 fffffffc7ffffbdf
    x12 0000000000000001  x13 ffffffffffffffff  x14 ffffffffffffff00  x15 ffffffffffffffff
    x16 0000007355bb12c0  x17 0000007355af033c  x18 0000000000000001  x19 0000000000007406
    x20 0000000000007406  x21 0000007fc6b27068  x22 00000072cfec2fe8  x23 0000000000000045
    x24 00000072c791f598  x25 0000007fc6b27348  x26 0000000000000000  x27 0000000000000001
    x28 0000000000000045  x29 0000007fc6b27050
    sp  0000007fc6b27010  lr  0000007355ae4e68  pc  0000007355ae4e90
backtrace:
    #00 pc 0000000000022e90  /system/lib64/libc.so (abort+116)
    #01 pc 0000000001287244  /data/app/ph.dudu.duduph-xxdPe23WLh6USaFzF3Frsw==/lib/arm64/libflutter.so (offset 0x126e000)
    #02 pc 00000000000020dc  [anon:.bss:00000072ae9aa000]
```

I tried searching for solutions but it seems like no one encountered the same problem yet. I also tried Invalidating the cache, flutter clean, and re-installing the app but the problem persists.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After 2 days, it's finally working again for Flutter. Just remove the mixpanel dependency and add it back again in `pubspec.yaml`. You can also try updating to the latest version (https://github.com/mixpanel/mixpanel-flutter/releases)

Answer (score 2):

In case of android add this line build.gradle
use mix panel library version 5.9.1
implementation 'com.mixpanel.android:mixpanel-android:5.9.1'

Comment: Mixpanel has released v5.9.2 & v5.9.3 just yesterday (October, 07, 2021).
This issue must have raised in these updates.

Comment: It seems like there is no fix yet for flutter

Comment: @AlRyanAcain try to use pervious version of mix panel I hope it will work.

Answer (score 0):

This issue has been ruined my day. now mixpanel has released a new version.

https://github.com/mixpanel/mixpanel-android/releases/tag/v5.9.4

Fixed in this version.

Comment: It seems like there is no fix yet for flutter